# Show the result of an int method in the Index View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I`ve made a simple method to count how many Albums do I have in a table, my only question is simple, I want to show the result of the Count method in the AlbumIndex view. Lets say I want to show a label: "Total" and the number besides it, how do I do this in the View?

This is the method(inside a class called Operations, separated from Controllers and Models):

```
 public int AlbumCounter()
        {
            int x = db.Albums.Count();
            return x;
        }
```

This is the ActionResult Method in my AlbumsController(I don`t know what to do, I want to show the result in the Index View)

```
public ActionResult AlbumCounter()
        {
            return
        }
```

and here is the Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Album>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Artist.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AlbumName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artist.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlbumName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AlbumID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AlbumID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AlbumID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: your index view `IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Album>` type, it os a collection, then in the controller you need to pass a collection  `public ActionResult Index() { return View(db.Albums)}`, and in the view  `<label>Total: <label> @Model.Count`

Comment: @DanielVorph: That would be much better as an answer.  As you can see, code does not translate well in comments.

Comment: @DanielVorph thanks, that`s a very good answer

Comment: @RobertHarvey I will consider next time, thanks